# How frame pointer recovers to the original address it pointed to?

Tags: computer-science

I'm reading about stack pointer and frame pointer on [Wiki - Call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

> (Section: Stack and frame pointers): *["] At function return, the stack pointer is instead restored to the frame pointer, the value of the stack pointer just before the function was called. Each stack frame contains a stack pointer to the top of the frame immediately below. [."]*

The part I don't understand is that supposed that during a procedure call `$fp` point to the address `$sp` point to before the call, so after the call we know how to recover `$sp` , but how about `$fp` itself?

Here is my homemade graph about my problem (the stack in my graph is supposed to growing from high address to low address):

[image: stack pointer 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the frame pointer (or, usually and more correctly, *previous* frame pointer) is pushed on to the stack as well so is recoverable with a simple `pop` instruction.

For example, here's a function in x86 with prolog and epilog (`ebp` is the frame pointer):

```
push    ebp                   ; push current frame pointer
mov     ebp, esp              ; set up frame pointer for this new frame
sub     esp, <frameSize>      ; allocate stack space (locals)

weave   magic                 ; the meat of the function

mov     esp, ebp              ; deallocate stack space
pop     ebp                   ; restore previous frame pointer
ret                           ; back to caller
```

In terms of what `$fp` contained *before* making the immediate call, it will have been the frame pointers for the most recent call *before* that. And this continues all the way up the call stack, until you reach the top (or find yourself using a different calling convention).

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you another question, also not related to my title, is that what's the address `$fp` point to before the call? I will draw a picture and edit my question about this specifically.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604, it's turtles all the way down :-) Or, more precisely, previous frame pointers all the way up (at least until you get to the top level, then it's whatever `ebp` happened to hold before we started making frames).

Comment: So is my logic correct: Each procedure call will require some space, which called a stack frame, with some pointers including two called `$sp` and `$fp`, and each such `$fp` point to the previous stack frame's top?

Comment: Thank you so much sir I think you must have written a very great answer but my current level cannot understand the meaning of code snippet you provided. But don't worry I will review it when I'm able to.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604: that's *exactly* it. Each stack frame contains enough information for the current level, *including how to get back to the previous level.*

Comment: lol, I now completely understand your answer! `mov     ebp, esp` is to move data in `esp` to `ebp`, but I thought it's the converse so I stuck...